# How to draw a vertical bar on top of a math symbol?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, draw

I can do `$_\tau^{|}$` which renders:

[image]

What I don't like is:

1. The `tau` becomes under the baseline
2. I can't control the line's length

Can someone help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with

```
$\stackrel{|}{\tau} $  base 
$\stackrel{\tikz{\draw[black] (0,1) -- (0,0) ;}}{\tau} $
```

the second option with `TikZ`.

[image]

Comment: Great! I wanted to be able to control the line's length, but I found that I can do `\substack{|\\ |}` and it's good enough. Thanks

Comment: @Mageek If you don't mind loading `TikZ`, with the last edit you should be able to do it quite at pleasure.

Answer (score 3):

If the vertical bar should a kind of math accent, you can use the following idea:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\vbar}[1]{{\vbar@accent{#1}}}
\newcommand\vbar@accent[1]{%
  \overset{%
    \text{\smash[b]{\rule[-0.4ex]{0.4pt}{0.8ex}}}% <-- customize 0.8ex
  }{#1}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$X+\vbar{\tau}_{\vbar{\tau}}$

\end{document}
```

[image]